# Using LIKE operator without limiting results

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following query, the objective of which is to display a list of "items" which contain a series of "tags". Furthermore, I have chosen to display only "5" tags for each "item" as you can appreciate below:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.*, 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name), ',', 5) tagList
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
                LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
                GROUP BY i.id");
```

Ok, that's great. It gives me something like this:

[ITEM 1] tag1, tag2, tag3, tag6, tag8

[ITEM 2] tag1, tag3, tag11, tag15, tag16

[ITEM 3] tag2, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7

etc

But here's the thing: if want to display a list of "items" which are "tagged" with "**tag2**" by adding:

```
WHERE (t.name LIKE 'tag2')
```

My result is simply:

[ITEM 1] **tag2**

[ITEM 3] **tag2**

Showing me the items that, in fact, are tagged with "**tag2**" but limiting the "tags" to just that one. What I *really want* as a result are these two items (the ones tagged as "**tag2**") with all their tags:

[ITEM 1] tag1, **tag2**, tag3, tag6, tag8

[ITEM 3] **tag2**, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7

I have tried to use

```
WHERE (tagList LIKE '%tag2%')
```

But that just gives me:

```
Invalid query: Unknown column 'tagList' in 'where clause'
```

I hope I made myself clear. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a short sample dump of your database so others can use it to try answers out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT i.*, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name), ',', 5) tagList
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING (tagList LIKE '%tag2%')
```

if you want to search all tags (not just the first 5) you can do it by JOIN-ing tags one more time:

```
SELECT i.*, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name), ',', 5) tagList
FROM items AS i
JOIN tag_rel as tr2 ON (tr2.item = i.id)
JOIN tags as t2 ON (t2.id = tr2.tag)
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
WHERE t2.name = 'tag2'
GROUP BY i.id
```

or with another `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT i.*, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name), ',', 5) tagList
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = i.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) LIKE '%tag2%')
```

You should also be aware that the `LIKE` solution will also match "tag2", "tag21","myTag2"... etc.

Comment: This is brilliant. I'm using the 3rd option and it works like a charm! I'm just wondering if it is better to just use Group_concat once (without limiting it to 5), and then do the limiting later with PHP in the tagList array. Do you think this is more server-friendly?

Comment: I doubt it will make a measurable difference.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the order in which MySQL executes Query. In general it first performs the `FROM ... JOIN ...` clause, then the `WHERE` clause and then the `SELECT`. Hence an alias created in in the `SELECT` clause can't be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: True, sorry. I didn't include it in the example :(